# ipad app running Core Location in background crashes

Tags: ipad, ios6, core-location

I've been working on this for a few days. Any idea what this means? please help!
let me know if more info is required

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
>
> Thread 11 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x200826b0.events
>       Thread 11 Crashed:
>       0   libdispatch.dylib               0x387b2420 dispatch_sync_f$VARIANT$mp + 0
>       1   CoreLocation                    0x393c8088         CLConnectionClient::setCachedResponse(CLConnectionMessage*, bool ( block_pointer)()) + 76
>       2   CoreLocation                    0x393c8558     __setDefaultMessageHandler_onQueue_block_invoke_0 + 28
>       3   CoreLocation                    0x393c7070 __setEventHandler_block_invoke_0 + 344
>       4   libxpc.dylib                    0x367ef7e4 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 768
>       5   libdispatch.dylib               0x387b6524 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 120
>       6   libdispatch.dylib               0x387b2e8e _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 78
>       7   libdispatch.dylib               0x387b67b2 _dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 158
>       8   libdispatch.dylib               0x387b2e8e _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 78
>       9   libdispatch.dylib               0x387b2dbc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 36
>       10  libdispatch.dylib               0x387b2e8e _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 78
>       11  libdispatch.dylib               0x387b2dbc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 36
>       12  libdispatch.dylib               0x387b391a _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 182
>       13  libdispatch.dylib               0x387b3abc _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
>       14  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34097a0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
>       15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x340978a0 start_wqthread + 4

```
- (void)startupLocationManager
{
    // startup location manager for background processing
    if (self.locationManager == nil)
    {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    }
}

- (void)stopLocationManager
{
    if (self.locationManager)
    {
        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
        self.locationManager = nil;

        if (self.isInBackground == YES)
        {
            [self startupLocationManager];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with help from other posts. It turned out to be a timing issue. I created another method to reset my location manager and I call it with a delay. This fixed everything. Hope this helps you too.

```
- (void)stopLocationManager
{
    if (locationManager)
    {
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        [self performSelector:@selector(discardLocationManager) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }
}

- (void) discardLocationManager
{
    locationManager.delegate = nil;
    locationManager = nil;

    if (self.isRestart == YES)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(startupLocationManager) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please comment on why this delay is needed? also can you share the links to other posts you mentioned? thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the scenario of the error ? I can not get the error manually. @LittlePeculiar